# Ionic 4 How To change templateUrl programatically?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I can't find an answer to this. I have a modal component that needs to display different forms depending on params at the time. I don't particularly want to have multiple components for different modals, so I wanted to be able to change templateUrl in the modal component based on the nav params at the time.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible. You'd need to change it within the @Component() function and input variables aren't available yet.

I assume your problem is you don't want to have a huge template with a bunch of conditionals I would solve this by making each form its own component (as you would anyway if you were trying to load different templates), so you'd end up with something like this as your modal template:

```
<app-form-one *ngIf="condition"></app-form-one>
<app-form-two *ngIf="condition2"></app-form-two>
<app-form-three *ngIf="condition3"></app-form-three>
```

Kind of a stupid simple solution but it works and is very clean, no hacking.

And if your aversion to this is having to move form handling info into the components, you can avoid that by passing a [formData] input property like this:

```
<app-form-three *ngIf="condition3" [formData]="formData"></app-form-three>
```